# after make a successful payment by PayPal APIs, the bank refund it

Tags: paypal

I use PayPal API order v2 for payment gateway.

```
def create_paypal_payment(token, amount):
    payment_payload = {
        'intent': 'CAPTURE',
        'purchase_units': [
            {
                'amount': {
                    'currency_code': 'GBP',
                    'value': str(amount),
                }
            }
        ],
        "payment_source": {
            "paypal": {
                "experience_context": {
                    "payment_method_preference": "IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED",
                    "brand_name": env.paypal_brand_name,
                    "locale": env.paypal_locale,
                    "landing_page": "LOGIN",
                    "shipping_preference": "NO_SHIPPING",
                    "user_action": "PAY_NOW",
                    "return_url": env.paypal_return_url,
                    "cancel_url": env.paypal_cancel_url
                }
            }
        }
    }

    payment_headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'
    }

    response = requests.post(f"https://{paypal_url}/v2/checkout/orders", data=json.dumps(payment_payload),
                             headers=payment_headers)

    return response
```

after create payment, I use payer_action link and make the payment

when I check the payment status, it was APPROVED and the amount was deducted from my bank accounts

after twenty minutes, the amount came back to my bank accoutn.
I need to call any other API after approved a payment?

Answer (score 2):

after APPROVED status, you have to send request to "capture order" and then status will be "COMPLETED"

Comment: Yep, based on the result of the capture request is when you show a success/failure message to the payer. Also redirects are an old integration pattern. Instead of redirecting away from your site for the approval at PayPal, keep your site loaded in the background and use https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ for approval

Comment: There's an interactive demo at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server